# Remove EntityProperties in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to create my own TableEntity to add EntityProperties dynamically in a  dictionary style.
For storing, reading and updating so far so good, the trick is to either override or implement the following functions.

`ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)`

`IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)`

However, I am not able to remove EntityProperty from my rows in Azure Table Storage.
For example, I have a row in my tablestorage with the following extra property:

`name:string`

When retrieving the property (e.g. ReadEntity) i get that EntityProperty from my TableStorage.
I Was under the impression that eveything I Pass through `WriteEntity` will end up in the table storage. But for example when i return an empty dictionary for `WriteEntity`, my entity in table storage remains unchanged. I would expect that if i supply no EntityProperty during a `merge`, the EntityProperties are deleted from the Table Storage for that row.

When I have more extra properties, e.g. `name` and `address`, and i remove `name` when the `WriteEntity` function is called and update `address`, `address` is updated and `name` remains unchanged instead of deleted.

tldr: **How do i remove an EntityProperty programatically from a TableEntity in such a way that it is removed from the Table Storage?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would expect that if i supply no EntityProperty during a merge, the
>   EntityProperties are deleted from the Table Storage for that row.

I believe there is a bit of misunderstanding regarding `merge` operation. A merge operation will only change the attributes that are included in the request. If an attribute that is present in the entity but is not there in the merge request, that attribute will remain unchanged.

If you want to remove an attribute from an entity completely, you will need to use `replace` operation instead of a `merge` operation. In case of a replace operation, an entity will be replaced with the entity you pass in the request. So it will only have those attributes that you specify in the request for a replace operation.

From [`Merge Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity#remarks) REST API documentation:

> **A property cannot be removed with a Merge Entity operation**. To remove
>   a property from an entity, replace the entity by calling the Update
>   Entity operation.